# How do I make `--cc` the default for merge diffs in Git?

Tags: git, merge

By default, `git log -p` does not show anything for merge commits. In the case of conflicts, I'd like to see the diff, and `git log -p --cc` does this. Is there a way to make `--cc` the default style for merge commit diffs in Git?

For more info on `--cc` diffs, see the `COMBINED DIFF FORMAT` section of `man git diff`, or [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/02/21/reviewing-merge-commits/).

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to set this as the default.  You can make an alias (`git config alias.lp `log --cc -p`, then `git lp`, for instance; or use a command shell alias) but that's a bit unsatisfactory.